# Socket programming: Is extra '\n' added in the golang client or the Java server?

Tags: java, sockets, go

I've written a Java TCP socket service and this service is used by a golang client.

Things get weird when the server socket response gets parsed on the golang side.

Specifically, this Java server code:

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output));
bw.append('Y');        
bw.append('E');
bw.append('S');
bw.append('\n');
bw.flush();
```

And this golang client code:

```
extendTimoutFor(client.conn)
    rspMsg, fault := bufio.NewReader(client.conn).ReadString('\n')
    if fault != nil {
        return UNKNOWN, fmt.Errorf("Ers reading response: %v", fault)
    }

    retStr := strings.TrimRight(rspMsg, "\n")

    if retStr == YES {
        return YES, nil
    }

    if retStr == NO {
        return NO, nil
    }

    if retStr == FAIL {
        return FAIL, nil
    }

    return UNKNOWN, fmt.Errorf("Ers parsing msg [%s]: %v", rspMsg, fault)
```

Produce this result in the client:

```
[UNDO|test|]: Ers parsing msg [YES
]: <nil>
```

My problem with the result is that the client doesn't recognize retStr as a valid response. Since rspMsg is what we expect (i.e. 'YES\n') then if we're in the *UNKNOWN* block it means that something went wrong during this line: *retStr := strings.TrimRight(rspMsg, "\n")*?

**My specific questions are:**

1. Since there are nil errors shouldn't '\n' and (any characters following it) have been stripped leaving us with "YES"?
2. Am I missing some quirk on the Java side? I've recreated the client using  Java and the output is what I expect.

Comment: What does rspMsg look like when you run the debugger? This is a perfect case to use one :-)

Comment: 1, 2, 3: Because you print `rspMsg`, not `retStr`. What is `YES`, `NO` and `FAIL`?

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider - alas, I don't run Go on my machine so I don't know... I requested the code for the client to figure out what's going on. Installing and running the Go client would be my next step.

Comment: @tkausl - great point. I will clarify the question. 
I assumed the [link]https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#TrimRight trimRight function works as advertised so I'm really trying to figure out why retStr seems to be incorrect.

`YES`, `NO` and `FAIL` are the results from the sever. They specify whether the string was in the correct format or not. For now, `YES` is hard-coded while I debug the client-side issue

Comment: In your code, `YES`, `NO`, and `FAIL` are variable references. That's why tkausl was asking what they are - what are their values? They aren't defined in your snippet. Your output message includes the newline because you're printing rspMsg, which is the original un-trimmed value. What do you get if you instead output retStr, which is your trimmed value?

Comment: @Adrian Ahhh! Thanks for clarifying. Yes, they are defined variables. See below. I've just installed go and I'm refactoring the code to make it work. I'll let you know as soon as I get it running locally

`const (
 //YES code
 YES = "YES"

 //FAIL code
 FAIL = "FAIL"

 //NO code
 NO = "NO"

 //UNKNOWN code
 UNKNOWN = "UNKNOWN"
)`

Comment: Issues on both sides but the root cause was in the Java server. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Since there are nil errors shouldn't '\n' and (any characters following it) have been stripped leaving us with "YES"?
   **YES**
2. Am I missing some quirk on the Java side? I've recreated the client using Java and the output is what I expect.
   **YES**

This was resolved with a few steps:

- Using java.io.PrintWriter introduced some unexpected characters throughout the output.
- strings.TrimRight(rspMsg, "\n") masked the point above but it was confirmed after installing Golang and debugging the script (using strings.TrimSpace for the operation above is a more robust approach)
- Switching to java.io.OutputStream.write() simplified the output sent to the client